# Remove the pointers from the chart?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

[image]

This is a simple UI I made to learn the charts API in JavaFX. The `AreaChart` looks great however, I was wondering if it is possible to **hide** the tiny dots that signify the plotted values ?

The reason is that as the dots come closer, when the value of X axis increases, they become smaller and harder to comprehend. Sometimes they overlap. In such a situation, the graph would be more legible without the dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call setNode(...) on the XYChart.Data objects and pass in something invisible.

For example:

```
XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(x,y);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0);
rect.setVisible(false);
data.setNode(rect);
```

Comment: Also, is it possible to make the chart scrollable ? Left-right or top-bottom ?

Comment: Don't use this method, use this instead: lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false); //hide dots

Comment: why is this the chosen answer and the one below is a better and working solution. This doesn't work at all.

Comment: Maybe because this is by James_D, who is awesome with JFX Q's on SO. However, I agree the other solution is better here. (Also this one does work, for me.)

Answer (score 44):

There is a method to hide the dots (or any other graphical representation of a x/y point).

```
    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    //here be code...

    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false); //hide dots
```

Comment: and is it possible to make it scrollable without using listeners and `setUpperBound()` and `setLowerBound()` ? :)

Comment: I think you should create a new question for that issue. There might be many ways to achieve a scrolling effect, but we need more infos about what should happen once you scroll on the chart.

Comment: also can be done in fxml with attribute  `createSymbols="false"`

Comment: If you're using SceneBuilder, you can just uncheck the "Create Symbols" attribute in the chart's Properties tab